# Average Function in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, installation, average

I'm just starting to learn Python from a book. But I keep running into the same problem when I run my script, it says:

```
   File "C:/Users/bob/Desktop/Python/Part3 A.py", line 8, in <module> print(' the average is: ', avg())
    File "C:/Users/Bob/Desktop/Python/Part3 A.py", line 6, in avg average = a + b + c / 3
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Did I install "Pycharm" wrong?

Here is my code

```
def avg():
a = input('please enter a: ')
b = input('please enter b: ')
c = input('please enter c: ')
average = a + b + c / 3
print(' the average is: ', avg())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Did I install "Pycharm" wrong? NO**

in python 3 `input` returns a string

```
a = int(input("please enter a:")) #this will make the input an integer 
# warning if the user enters invalid input it will raise an error
```

should work fine

you should also change your print line to

```
print(' the average is: ', avgerage)
```

you also need to pay attention to order of operations when you calculate the average

```
average = (a + b + c) / 3
```

is what you want

you also have indentation problems but im pretty sure thats cause you copied and pasted wrong ... otherwise you would have a different error

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to divide a string by an integer. 
You need to convert your inputs to integers.

```
def avg():
    a = int(input('please enter a: '))
    b = int(input('please enter b: '))
    c = int(input('please enter c: '))
    average = (a + b + c) / 3
    return average

print(' the average is: ', avg())
```

Comment: Woops. I just copied and pasted, didn't notice this in the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
def avg():
a = intinput('please enter a: ')
b = input('please enter b: ')
c = input('please enter c: ')
average = a + b + c / 3
print(' the average is: ', avg())
```

try this instead

```
def avg():
 a = input('please enter a: ')
 b = input('please enter b: ')
 c = input('please enter c: ')
 average = int(a) + int(b) + int(c) / 3
 print(' the average is: ', avg())
return;
```

P.S: Python is indent sensitive

Comment: this will not work ... although you are partially right in that he needs to worry about order of operations `"1" + "2" +"3" = "123"` the fact that you put it in parenthesis does little to alieviate that you cannot divide a string by an int

Comment: i noticed that and i edited thanks for the notice he also need to do some error handling when dividing

Answer (score 1):

You've got many errors, which are as follows:

```
def avg():
    a = int(input('Please enter a: '))
    b = int(input('Please enter b: '))
    c = int(input('Please enter c: '))
    average = (a + b + c) / 3
    print('The average is:', average)

avg() # call function outside
```

- Indent 4 spaces under the scope of the function.
- Cast the string input to integers with built-in `int`.
- Use parenthesis, otherwise math is wrong by PEMDAS.
- Lastly, print the average, don't call function recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying arithmetic operations on string input. Convert it to int before using

> int(input('please enter a: '))